# Is there a way to dynamically get the RowHeight of a ListView item for use in setting the width of a Grid column?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with HasUnevenRows set to "true". Within the ListView.ItemTemplate I have a grid for which I'd like to dynamically set the ColumnDefinition Width to the Height of the ListView item. The end goal is to get a grid cell that is a perfect square regardless of Platform and ListView row content.

Is there a way for me to get the current value of the ListView item's row and set it in the ColumnDefinition in the ListView.ItemTemplate? Is this something I can do without the use of a custom renderer?

Here's a mock-up XAML representing what I'd like to achieve:

```xml
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions Width=" LISTVIEW ITEM ROW HEIGHT "/>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
                </Grid>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RowHeight` Property to set the height of a row of ListView. And then use Converter to set the width of gird dynamically.

Create a converter:

```
 public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView
        x:Name="listView"
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding peoples}"
        RowHeight="100">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Accent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=RowHeight, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=RowHeight, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=RowHeight, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <BoxView
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Black" />
                        <BoxView
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BackgroundColor="Blue" />
                        <BoxView
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                        <BoxView
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BackgroundColor="DarkGray" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I use `BoxView` to represent the square regardless which colored the black.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I kind of thought I would do this if there wasn't a way to ascertain each Row's height. The problem with that is that when setting RowHeight explicitly, it's shape around the contents varies depending on the platform, so if I do this I'll have to make a ResourceDictionary or some sort of reference to set the height for each platform. Not a terrible solution, I was just hoping there was something more programatic.

Comment: The listview would fill the empty space, if we do not set the value, when try to get the height without initial value, it would throw the error.  You could try to get the screen height and the value would change depending on the platform.